# How can resolve an URL on a specific DNS server

Tags: node.js, server, http

I'm currently facing a issue on a project.
I'm resolving URL's on multiple DNS servers using a node.js server.
Until here, everything is fine.

But some ISP restrict the incoming requests from IPs outside their IP range.

So how could I modify my request to those specific DNS servers to make it look like I'm one of their clients?

If I understand DNS request correctly, there are no such things as x-forwarded-for header as an HTTP request would have.

So can it be achieve ? Or am I facing a real blocker ?

(I hope I am on the correct stackexchange for this question)

Comment: You are facing a real blocker.  They know which side of the network the traffic is coming from, and really, when the traffic gets there its numbers - not a name.  That said, what URLs are you trying to resolve on DNS servers?

Comment: I'm trying to build a service to test the integrity of DNS servers. So that could be any URL to virtually every DNS servers. This could be a-social-network.com to a Iran ISP's DNS server or my-blog.me to google DNS server (which isn't a problem).

Comment: Are you trying to do [this](http://imgur.com/2MXXEaD) for arbitrary dns servers and hosts in node.js?

Comment: If you send a DNS request with a fake IP as the source, then your answer will be sent back to the IP the request seemed to come from - the fake IP; thus making the exercise pointless.

Comment: You can do this with authoritative DNS servers (the servers that are listed in NS record delegations). But resolvers typically restrict themselves to clients; the main exceptions are public DNS servers like OpenDNS and Google Public DNS.

Comment: Even if they did allow access, another difficulty you'll run into is that large ISPs use _anycast_ for their DNS server addresses. What this means is that the server IP (e.g. 8.8.8.8 for Google) will be routed to different machines depending on where the client is, for load balancing and improved response time. So just because 8.8.8.8 succeeds for you, it doesn't mean it will succeed for someone else.